# Printing modal window with modified values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JS to set a series of checkboxes in a modal window depending on value sent to it.  I can print the modal window - however, only the default values are printed, not any dynamically updated values.

How can I

HTML of modal window

```
<div id="switchSettings" class="modal" style="z-index: 4; display: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" id="checkCriteria[1]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[2]" id="checkCriteria[2]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[3]" id="checkCriteria[3]" value="4" />
    ...(and so on)
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[21]" id="checkCriteria[21]" value="1048576" />
</div>
```

PHP function on processing page sums all set checkboxes and stores an integer, a unique ID, and friendly name to database.  User is presented with the friendly names of saved data to click which

Function to set array of checkboxes - uses binary operators to convert an Int into 20 odd "dip switches" (checkboxes styled via css).

```
function setCheckArray(binaryValues) {
    document.getElementById("switchSettings").style.display = "block";
    for(i = 1; i < 22; i++) {
        checkboxname = "checkCriteria[" + i + "]";
        document.getElementById(checkboxname).checked = false;
        if(document.getElementById(checkboxname).value == (document.getElementById(checkboxname).value & binaryValues)) {
            document.getElementById(checkboxname).checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Function to print only the modal

```
function printModalWindow(modalID){
    // To us pass document.getElementById('divtoprint') as argument
    var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow", "width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");

    WindowObject.document.writeln("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./css/css.css\">");
    WindowObject.document.writeln("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./css/font-awesome.css\">");

    WindowObject.document.writeln(modalID.innerHTML);

    WindowObject.document.close();

    setTimeout(function(){
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
    },6000);
}
```

User presented with buttons with "onclick=setCheckArray(3748592);" etc that cause the modal to popup and set the array of dipswitches.  This part works perfectly, it is keeping the switch positions (checkbox values) from the modal in printing.

Any suggestions?